# When can I expect Italian regional train tickets to be available for purchase?

Tags: trains, italy

I need to travel from Lecco to Rome by train, in July. I am used to buying a single journey on a single ticket, since I believe that I will get more assistance if I bought the journey that way and the first train was late - compared to what I would get if I travelled with two separate tickets.

The problem is that timetables or prices for Lecco-Milan are not yet available, but tickets for the Milan-Rome leg are being sold and prices may rise based on demand. I know I can buy Lecco-Milan from the station for a fair price, but I am concerned about the transfer if I had two tickets.

When can I expect the regional tickets to be available in Trenitalia's website? Should I simply book Milan-Rome separately from Trenitalia or even from Italo to avoid paying too much? Is doing a single purchase a less risky strategy, anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by multiple tickets giving you better protection. Usually, having multiple tickets gives you _less_ protection, because the transit provider is only responsible for getting you from A to B, when you're actually going to C. Surely, if you have two trains on the same ticket, and the first one is delayed, you'll be allowed to use that ticket on the next available connection?

Comment: In some countries it does not matter whether you have one or two tickets as long as have enough connexion time. Do you know how these companies handle this?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes I agree. That's my original plan here, buying a single ticket from A to C. It's just not available yet, since A to B only has timetable and prices for 3 weeks ahead, so I'm thinking about buying B to C beforehand

Comment: I would expect the connection to be protected because it is a) between two trains of the same company and b) they do not sell through tickets anyway. Just respect the minimum connection time. (15 min. at Centrale, 10 at Garibaldi)

Answer (score 2):

The Trenitalia timetable changes twice a year, and the 2019 summer timetable will start on June 9th.

Usually the timetable is not loaded on the website all at once: high-speed trains are available earlier, while regional trains are the last to be updated. This is the reason why at the moment you can find the Rome-Milan trains but not Milan-Lecco.

The complete Intercity (long distance, not high-speed) timetable will be uploaded by May 18th (http://www.fsnews.it/fsn/Gruppo-FS-Italiane/Trenitalia/Trenitalia-offerta-Intercity-confermata-anche-nel-prossimo-cambio-orario-estivo), and it is reasonable to expect that the regional train timetable will also be available within a couple of weeks.